# "The provided token has expired" after upgrade to Amplify version 2

Tags: android, aws-amplify

After upgrading to Amplify version 2, I get this error when I try to upload photos using Amplify library, What should I do to fix this issue

```
SinglePartUploadWorker failed with exception: aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The provided token has expired.
                                                                                                    at aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.transform.PutObjectOperationDeserializerKt.throwPutObjectError(PutObjectOperationDeserializer.kt:66)
                                                                                                    at aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.transform.PutObjectOperationDeserializerKt.access$throwPutObjectError(PutObjectOperationDeserializer.kt:1)
                                                                                                    at aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.transform.PutObjectOperationDeserializerKt$throwPutObjectError$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:13)
                                                                                                    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

Gradle

```
//     Amplify core dependency
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:2.8.4'
```

MainApplication class

```
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSCognitoAuthPlugin());
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSS3StoragePlugin());
Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext());
```

and I added the configuration files to

```
res/raw/amplifyconfiguration.json
res/raw/awsconfiguration.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my android app. You have to remove the auth and add it again using Amplify CLI commands.

Commands:

```
amplify init
amplify remove auth  
amplify push  
amplify pull  

amplify init
amplify add auth  
amplify push  
amplify pull
```